# Re-deploy EJB-jar causes dependant war-files to stop working

Tags: java, ejb

I have a several war-files that depends on a `ejb-jar` that I re-deploy. This causes all dependant war-applications to stop working and I get this error: "`javax.servlet.ServletException: $Proxy451 cannot be cast to com.posten.ejb.SessionHome`".

The war-files contains a `client-jar` for accessing the `EJB`, only containing the Home- and RemoteInterfaces.

I'm running my apps on `JBoss 4.2.3.`

Regards Mats